# Why is Rust's std::thread::sleep allowing my HTTP response to return the correct body?

Tags: http, tcp, rust

I am working on the beginning of the final chapter of The Rust Programming Language, which is teaching how to write an HTTP response with Rust.

For some reason, the HTML file being sent does not display in the browser unless I have Rust wait before calling `TcpResponse::flush()`.

Here is the code:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::fs;
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        handle_connection(stream);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    let contents = fs::read_to_string("hello.html").unwrap();
    
    let response = format!(
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n{}",
        contents.len(),
        contents
    );

    stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    // let i = stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    // println!("{} bytes written to the stream", i);
    // ^^ using this code instead will sometimes make it display properly
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    // ^^ uncommenting this will cause a blank page to load.

    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
```

I observe the same behavior in multiple browsers.

According to the Rust book, calling `TcpListener::flush` should ensure that the bytes finish writing to the stream. So why would I be unable to view the HTML file in the browser unless I sleep the thread before flushing?

I have done hard reloading and restarted the server with `cargo run` multiple times and the behavior is the same. I have also printed out the file contents to the terminal, and the contents are being read fine under either condition (of course they are).

I wonder if this is a problem with my operating system. I'm on Windows 10.

It isn't really holding the project up as I can continue learning (and I'm not planning on putting an actual web project into production right now), but I would appreciate any insight anyone has on this issue. There must be something about Rust's handling of the stream or the environment that I am not understanding.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I see you're reading the incoming request into a 1024-byte buffer. Have you checked that this buffer is large enough to read the whole request? If not, try enlarging your buffer. Just a guess. :)

Comment: This is no valid HTTP. There is a `\r\n` missing after the `Content-Length: ...\r\n` to separate HTTP header and HTTP body. Please fix this issue and check if your problem still occurs. Another problem is that you don't have any `Content-Type` header, so the browser has to guess what kind of content you are serving.

Comment: Hmmm, those responses might make me doubt it, but the problem is that when I do call `sleep`, the content does load. So clearly the HTML format is not wrong enough to be the main factor. Unless I am missing something deeper.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, the whole string is the output of `format!("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n{}", contents.len(), contents)`. Is there supposed to be a third CRLF somewhere? The book is telling me 2, one after the status code and one after the headers.

Comment: @PeterCharland There needs to be two CRLF sequences at the end of the headers, one at the end of the last header and one more to mark the end of the headers. In other words, there must a blank line between the headers and the body.

Comment: @PeterCharland: *"The book is telling me  ..."* - please look careful at the example at [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html?highlight=content-length#returning-real-html) and you will realize that you are missing a `\r\n`. To cite from Listing 20-5: `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n\r\n{}"`.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, but you should use `stream.write_all` to ensure that the whole response is written to the stream.

Comment: Ah OK! Thanks guys. I will try it with those details added later today and let you know what the outcome is.

Comment: Okay, guys, thanks. I'm still not sure why calling `thread::sleep` would affect it, but my response definitely was missing a CRLF. between the headers and body. It does appear to solve the problem. Still curious why giving it more time somehow allowed the response to load, though. The main thing is I now know what the difference was between my project and the walkthrough. In any case, thanks for the help!